# Count number of regexp matches in a Queryset regexp filter in Django

Tags: python, django

I've a queryset I'm running in a django view.

```
sp = Session.objects.filter(year__gte=start_year, year__lte=end_year, data__iregex=word_to_search_for_re)
```

Although it says word_to_search_for, this can be a couple of words separated by whitespace.

What I want to do is count how many times the match occurs in data. At the moment, I'm pulling the results from this queryset back and doing this manually, which seems like a grossly inefficient code smell. I've seen something called annotations (https://medium.com/@singhgautam7/django-annotations-steroids-to-your-querysets-766231f0823a), but not sure how to get this to work in this case or if I'm asking too much.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`.count()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#count):

```
n_sp = Session.objects.filter(
    year__gte=start_year, year__lte=end_year, data__iregex=word_to_search_for_re
).count()
```

This will move the counting to the database, and so the database can boost this, since it does not have to serialize all data, and pass a huge chunk of data.

You can also shorten the query to:

```
n_sp = Session.objects.filter(
    year__range=(start_year, end_year), data__iregex=word_to_search_for_re
).count()
```

Comment: Really is that simple Thanks :)